# Visual studio community: License expired and License error (0x00000010): Cached online license container is corrupt.?

Tags: visual-studio, licensing

My Visual studio community license expired (it is VS2013 but it might also apply to VS2015).

[image]

When I click "Check for an updated license" or "Sign in", I get `License error (0x00000010): Cached online license container is corrupt`.

[image]

What should I do? I know there are other questions about this problem, but I could not find a solution yet.

Comment: It seems that some people consider this kind of questions as off-topic, and advise to ask on some Microsoft website. However I am deeply convinced that SO is a much better platform for this problem.

Comment: As a vendor product, the vendor's forum and support channels are the first you should resort to.

Comment: But stackoverflow is much better, so what is the point of using a bad tool when there is a better free one?

Comment: But you are right, so I posted my question [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/854dc1ce-2836-4191-aa8a-9fa89e8c86e2/visual-studio-community-license-expired-and-license-error-0x00000010-cached-online-license?forum=visualstudiogeneral) (and markdown did not work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled then reinstalled Visual Studio 2013 and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was apparently that my MSDN license for a corporation to which I previously belonged was listed as the 'default' entry on my MSDN account. Changing it to the right license did not fix the problem right away, but after a few days it did reset itself.

Answer (score 0):

Delete IE cache or clear the license information in registry

From here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/854dc1ce-2836-4191-aa8a-9fa89e8c86e2/visual-studio-community-license-expired-and-license-error-0x00000010-cached-online-license?forum=visualstudiogeneral

> According to the error message, please try clear all caches in IE first. Then restart Visual Studio Community to sign in again. 
>   If it still has the same problem, please try to clear the license information in registry as below path(if it exist). Then restart VS to sign in again.
>   `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Licenses\*`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20509238)

Answer (score 0):

Resetting credentials is worked for me.

Open CMD then Go to visual studio path where devenv.exe exist, Forexample:

> cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\

Then reset credentials by the following commands:

> devenv /resetsettings
>
> devenv /resetuserdata
>
> devenv /safemode

devenv /resetuserdata is the one that worked for me.

I opened vs after this command and the error message was gone.